# No puedo ver los valores fuera del suscribe en Angular

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular7

Por favor espero me puedan ayudar, lo que quiero es convertir el resultado de una lista en un JSON para que el DataSource de  lo pueda leer y desplegar la tabla.
logró obtener los valores de Producto y CalcularImporte de Venta pero todo dentro del suscribe.
Como podria hacer para obtenerlos fuera del suscribe, porque afuera solo obtendo los valores mediante console.log(this.lstDetalleVenta2), es por ello que en la primera iteración también el console.log(jsonArray) sale vacio;
Me parece que hay un retraso en el  console.log(jsonArray) éste se entera de lo hecho todavía en la siguiente inserción de registro, por eso en la primera iteración salen vacios.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-venta',
  templateUrl: './venta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venta.component.css']
})
export class VentaComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['producto', 'precio','cantidad', 'total','eliminar'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Venta>;
  idPersonaSeleccianda: number;
  idProductoSeleccionado: number;

  lstDetalleVenta2 : DetalleVenta[] = [];

costo : number;
  agregar(){
    let producto = new Producto();
    let dVenta = new DetalleVenta();

    this.productoService.listarPorId(this.idProductoSeleccionado).subscribe( p => {
      producto.nombre = p.nombre;
      producto.precio = p.precio;
      dVenta.producto = producto;
      dVenta.cantidad = this.cantidad;

      console.log('suscribe: '+ dVenta.calcularImporte());//si muestra en la primera ejecucion
      this.costo = dVenta.calcularImporte();//si muestra en la primera ejecucion
      this.lstDetalleVenta2.push(dVenta);
    })
    
    console.log(this.lstDetalleVenta2); //si muestra los valores de la primera ejecucion
    console.log('=== '+this.costo);//no muestra en la primera ejecucion

    //jsonArray, en la primera ejecucion sale vacio a pesar de que arriba this.lstDetalleVenta2
    // si muestra valores
    let jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lstDetalleVenta2));
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(jsonArray);
    console.log(jsonArray);

  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

La carga de los datos por medio de la subscripción se ejecuta hasta que este exista un valor nuevo disponible en el observable, es decir que se va ejecutar manera asíncrona, es por esta razón que en de primera entrada **this.lstDetalleVenta2** será un arreglo vacío ya que los datos aún no están disponibles.

Te recomiendo que llenes la lista dentro de la subscripción de esta manera:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-venta',
  templateUrl: './venta.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venta.component.css']
})
export class VentaComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns = ['producto', 'precio', 'cantidad', 'total', 'eliminar'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource < Venta > ;
  idPersonaSeleccianda: number;
  idProductoSeleccionado: number;

  lstDetalleVenta2: DetalleVenta[] = [];

  costo: number;
  agregar() {
    let producto = new Producto();
    let dVenta = new DetalleVenta();

    this.productoService.listarPorId(this.idProductoSeleccionado).subscribe(p => {
      producto.nombre = p.nombre;
      producto.precio = p.precio;
      dVenta.producto = producto;
      dVenta.cantidad = this.cantidad;

      console.log('suscribe: ' + dVenta.calcularImporte());
      this.costo = dVenta.calcularImporte();
      this.lstDetalleVenta2.push(dVenta);
      let jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.lstDetalleVenta2));
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(jsonArray);
      console.log(jsonArray);
      console.log(this.lstDetalleVenta2); 
      console.log('=== ' + this.costo); 
    })
  }
}
```

Recuerda además desubscribirte en el ngOnDestroy para evitar fugas de memoria.